# How can I correct the standard error for estimated marginal means (EMMs)?

Tags: r, emmeans

When I use the `emmeans` package in R to calculate the difference between means of two groups over time, I get the same standard error for each mean difference. It appears to be using all the data in the dataset to calculate the standard error when *I think* it should just use the data that is used to calculate the mean (e.g., similar to the results from a t-test). Any ideas on how to fix this?

Reproducible Example:

```
library(emmeans)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 36))
x <- c("Age","Location","Treatment","Value")
colnames(df1) <- x
df1$Age <- as.factor(rep(c(1,2,3), each = 12))
df1$Location <- as.factor(rep(c("Central","North"), each = 6))
df1$Treatment <- as.factor(rep(c("Control","Treatment"), each = 3))
df1$Value <- round(rnorm(36,200,25),0)

m1 <- lm(Value ~ Age * Treatment * Location, data = df1)
emm <- emmeans(m1,  ~ Treatment | Age, by = "Location")
emm # difference between control and treatment is correct, however see how the SE is the same for all differences?
emm_pairs <- pairs(emm, by = c("Age","Location"))

# figure below shows how mean difference is correct, but see how all the confidence intervals are the same size? this does not seem correct.

plot(emm_pairs, by = "Location", CIs = TRUE) +
  labs(x = "Mean Value (± SE)",
       y = "Age") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = c("1","2","3")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        strip.background =element_rect(fill="white"))
```

Comment: I think these results are correct.  The assumption under the linear model is that the residual variance is homogeneous across observations, which will lead to equal SEs for every group.

Comment: I could easily be using the wrong test then (`emmeans` in new to me). I was thinking I could get a mean difference and 95% CI using `emmeans`, similar to the results one would get from a `t.test`.

Comment: See the FAQs vignette in emmeans, where it talks about the Welch test.